# Add to cart button wont work

Tags: cart, magento-1, products, addtocart

I found this code through Google to add a Button to my shopping cart page under where I have some products begin displayed. However when I click on the button, it redirects me to the shopping cart but nothing is being added to the cart and I do not know why.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/')?>product/<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>/')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

This is my full block of code for the products to be displayed in my cart after some changes:

```
    <div class="upsell">

<?php if (Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() < 75.00)
{?>
 <h1><?php echo 'We see your subtotal is under £75, why not add these products to qualify for Free Delivery';?></h1>
 <br>
<?php

$categoryid = 1054;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');



$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
?>
<div class="upsell_products">

<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php foreach ($collection as $_product){ ?>



<div class="product">
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">

<div class="product_img_cart">

<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>" /></a>
</div>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
<p class="upsell_pro_name"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></p>
<p class="upsell_pro_price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice());?></a></p>
<div class="add_cart_btn">
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</div>
<?php if($i++ == 3) break; ?>

<?php } }
```

If you can help that would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused because your question title doesn't match what you're asking in the body.

Comment: You can test this: onclick="setLocation('<?php //echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)?>')  ??

Comment: @andyjv sorry that was form an old post, have changed now.

Comment: @osrecio nah didnt seem to work :(

Comment: You remove the slashes = "//" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)?>') ??

Comment: Check your Magento logs in `/var/log/system.log` and `/var/log/exception.log` and let us know what the most recent errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one thing:

- Load product by product id ($_product->getId()).

  $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
- Then use:

$product instead on $_product in onclick. Code is below:

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>')"
```

I hope, it will help.

Below is the updated code for working Add To Cart Url:

```
<div class="upsell">

<?php if (Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() < 75.00)
{?>
 <h1><?php echo 'We see your subtotal is under £75, why not add these products to qualify for Free Delivery';?></h1>
 <br>
<?php

$categoryid = 1054;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');



$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
?>
<div class="upsell_products">

<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php foreach ($collection as $_product){ ?>
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());?>


<div class="product">
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">

<div class="product_img_cart">

<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>" /></a>
</div>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
<p class="upsell_pro_name"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></p>
<p class="upsell_pro_price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice());?></a></p>
<div class="add_cart_btn">
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</div>
<?php if($i++ == 3) break; ?>

<?php } }
```

Comment: where should i put this line ??  $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());

Comment: where you have <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/')?>product/<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>/')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

here you need to just change onclick action and load product before that line.

Comment: Nah it just re directs me to the cart again without adding anything.

Comment: I think you are not understanding my point. I have said to first load product from product id then use that variable instead of $_product while passing in getAddToCartUrl function.

Comment: i just keep getting this error 

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/senorehe/public_html/app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml on line 133

Comment: I have added my whole block of code to my question, I am putting the $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId()); after my collection lines then changing the button, but it isnt wokring. Sorry if i dont understand what you are telling me i am quite new to this still, which is why i thought i would add more code.

Comment: Please check my edited answer now and let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! thank you so much for all of your help you have been brilliant!

Comment: @MohitKumarArora My code -> https://justpaste.it/6tp4f  Add to cart not working, could you pls help me to solve this error. Error message Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0  in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Cmsmart\AjaxCart\controllers\IndexController.php on line 209